error building angular v17.1.0 after installing angular-slickgrid v7.7.0
I have installed angular-slickgrid v7.7.0 and imported [AngularSlickgridModule] in the component.ts of new angular v17.1.0 project with SSR enabled and typescript v5.2.2. From the time I installed angular-slickgrid and imported the module, I started getting build error as follows:
[vite] Erro when evaluating SSR module /main.server.mjs: TypeError: Cannnot convert undefined or null to object at Function.getPrototypeOf (<anonymous>) at node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/utils.js.
I tried different options available on the web but of no use. Please advice. Thanks.
